# Volley JsonObjectRequest with Basic Auth headers didn't work

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley, basic-authentication, jsonobjectrequest

I'm trying to send username and password as basic authorization with JsonObjectRequest. I've tried to Override `getHeaders()` method but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
public class NewPostRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

    public NewPostRequest(JSONObject requestBody) {
        super(Method.POST, APIConstants.CREATE_POST_URL, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    long postId = response.getLong("id");

                    NewPostResponse newPostResponse = new NewPostResponse(postId);

                    EventBus.getDefault().post(newPostResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new NewPostResponse(-1));

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                EventBus.getDefault().post(new NewPostResponse(-1));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

        String credentials = "****:***********************";

        String auth = "Basic "
                + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        headers.put("Authorization", auth);

        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {

            String data = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return Response.success(jsonObject, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```

Error when i used `Base64.NO_WRAP`:

```
com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

And when i used `Base64.DEFAULT`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x0a at 46 in header value: Basic *************************
```

**Note:** This web service is working on Google Postman tool.

Comment: Did you check for the server logs?

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: @IbrahimDisouki how did you solve it?